# Get child of element by attribute value

Tags: jquery, dom, selector

I have a jQuery object representing a DIV:

```
$rel = $('#rel_'+rel.id);
```

In that DIV, there is a BUTTON with my custom attribute "rid" set to rel.id

I need to select that button, it works like this:

```
$("[rid='"+rel.id+"']").html();
```

But I think that's not the fastest possible solution as it needs to parse the whole DOM for that and because I know the button is always inside the DIV, I could avoid that.

I tried it with the following code:

```
$rel.children("[rid='"+rel.id+"']").html();
```

but that didn't work.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If it may not be an immediate child, you'll want [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) rather than `children` (which only looks at immediate children):

```
$rel.find("[rid='"+rel.id+"']").html();
```